# How to merge two columns into one in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Want to merge two columns into one column in certain condition.
My data is like below

```
idx    A    B
0      0.5  1.2
1      1.1  0.7
2      0.1  0.3
3      2.0  0.9
```

With Pandas dataframe, I want to make column C in the condition.

1. if column A > column B, column C gets the value of column A.
2. if column B > column A, column C gets the value of column B.

In **result**, I expect like this.

```
idx    A    B    C
0      0.5  1.2  1.2(B data)
1      1.1  0.7  1.1(A data)
2      0.1  0.3  0.3(B data)
3      2.0  0.9  2.0(A data)
```

I tried .loc function like:
`df['C'] = df.loc[df['A'] > df['B'], 'A']`

But I cannot replace or modify `Nan` value in column C.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you can use:

```
df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']>df['B'], df['A'], df['B'])
```

Comment: It also works! thanks!